# Textbox value not being multiplied when checkbox selected (HTML & Javascript/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code updates the CPC textbox when options are selected, but when an agency discount is selected (i.e. the 10% checkbox), it successfully lowers the CPC textbox value by 10% but does not do the same for the Total Cost textbox.

The Total Cost textbox value should be the (CPC textbox value * number of clicks textbox) * percentdiscount multiplier

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I'll be happy to clarify further if I haven't explained this very well!

HTML:

```
<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id="sum" type="text" readonly="true" value="0.00" data-total="0" />
  Total Cost (in £): <input id="totalcost" type="text" readonly="true" value="0 (until clicks specified)" data-total="0" />
</div>

<div class="black_whitelisting">
    <h1>4. Blacklist/Whitelist?</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" class="blacklist" name="blacklist" value="0.20" id="blacklist_checkbox" onclick="BlacklistFunction()">Blacklist required<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="whitelist" name="whitelist" value="0.30" id="whitelist_checkbox">Whitelist required<br>
</div>

<div class="selecttier">
    <h1>5. Number of Clicks</h1>
    <input id="numberofclickstextbox" type="text" value="0.00" data-total="0" oninput="calculatetier()" />
</div>

<div class="agencydiscount">
  <h1>6. Agency Discount</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" value="1" checked>
    None
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.9" onclick="calculatetotalcost10()" >
    10% Discount
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.85" onclick="calculatetier15()" >
    15% Discount
  </label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;        
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });

  function applyDiscount() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    $('#sum').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
  }
});

//to work out total cost    
function calculatetier() {
        var myBox5 = document.getElementById('numberofclickstextbox').value;    
        var myBox6 = document.getElementById('sum').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('totalcost');  
        var myResult = myBox5 * myBox6;
        result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
    }
```

Comment: I think you missed to call the some function like `calculatetotalcost10() `,`calculatetier15()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are calculatetier function isn't being called during the change of discount.

Working Demo: https://codepen.io/punith/pen/gOpaVxr?editors=1010

**HTML code**

```
<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id="sum" type="text" readonly="true" value="0.00" data-total="0" />
  Total Cost (in £): <input id="totalcost" type="text" readonly="true" value="0 (until clicks specified)" data-total="0" />
</div>

<div class="black_whitelisting">
    <h1>4. Blacklist/Whitelist?</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" class="blacklist" name="blacklist" value="0.20" id="blacklist_checkbox" >Blacklist required<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="whitelist" name="whitelist" value="0.30" id="whitelist_checkbox">Whitelist required<br>
</div>


<div class="selecttier">
    <h1>5. Number of Clicks</h1>
    <input id="numberofclickstextbox" type="text" value="0.00" data-total="0" oninput="calculatetier()" />
</div>

<div class="agencydiscount">
  <h1>6. Agency Discount</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" value="1" checked>
    None
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.9"  >
    10% Discount
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.85"  >
    15% Discount
  </label>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
function calculatetier() {
        var myBox5 = document.getElementById('numberofclickstextbox').value;    
        var myBox6 = document.getElementById('sum').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('totalcost');      
  if(myBox6=="0.00"){
          myBox6 =1;
        }
console.log(myBox6)
        var myResult = myBox5 * myBox6;
        result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
    }
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;        
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });
//to work out total cost    

  function applyDiscount() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    $('#sum').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
    calculatetier()
  }
});
```

Comment: this is much closer thank you! It's doing something weird for me though in that when a checkbox is unselected the value isn't returning to the original value. Is this happening for you? (for example, if you run your code, click blacklist and type in 1,000 clicks, when you click 10% the total cost value isnt changing?)

Comment: Yes, it isn't changing. Please. check the updated working code at https://codepen.io/punith/pen/gOpaVxr?editors=1011

Answer (score -1):

try to use onchange event instead I guess the event you are binding is not correct

`<input id="numberofclickstextbox" type="text" value="0.00" data-total="0" onchange="calculatetier()" />`